# Problems using aws-sdk in the browser with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, aws-sdk

I am working on browser based application that makes use of aws-sdk. I am using browserify for my app code but have not figured out how to roll aws into it. I have tried a couple of different approaches:

```
//MyApp.js - Take 1 using downloaded minified version
var AWS = require ('./aws-sdk.min.js');
...
AWS.config.region='us-east-2';
...
```

results in *Cannot set property 'region' of undefined*

My guess is that this doesn't work because browserify does not resolve the minified code.

```
//MyApp.js - Take 2 using downloaded development version
var AWS = require ('./aws-sdk.js');
```

This does not compile. Browserify reports *Error: Cannot find module '../lib/core'*.

Is there a trick to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I used AWS in the browser I set my region depending on the service I need, for example:

`new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15', credentials, region})`

So this made me wonder, maybe the version you downloaded is encapsulated and not exposing anything for browserify.

First I tested the version in the browser as follows:

```js
console.log(AWS)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.184.0/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>
```

Everything looked good so then I went ahead and tested on browserify.

Turns out you are reassigning the AWS global variable when you do:

`var AWS = require ('./aws-sdk.min.js');`

But you are already bundling it, so you are good, what you need to do is the following:

```
require ('./aws-sdk.min.js');
// And then use it happily
AWS.config.region='us-east-2';
```

**Without reassigning the AWS global variable**

Comment: Thank you @Claudiordgz . That worked. It was the reassigning of the global that killed me.

Comment: @Elsporko, it still happens to me often! Specially when bundling with webpack.